# In Windows Task Scheduler, Task runs at startup

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, tasks

So i have a Sleep.bat file that runs at say 10pm.

Sometimes, it runs the next morning when i turn on my computer.

it has always had the box unchecked
next to "run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed."

your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps run Task Scheduler with Run as Administrator and reset turn on times that way

Comment: On days when this happens, was the computer turned off the previous day before 10 PM?